# Disconnecting pool pump housing from piping

Tags: pool, pump

The impeller on the housing for my pool pump sprung a leak and so I'm trying to replace it.  I have the replacement housing, but I'm having trouble removing the old housing.  The housing is thread connected at the top to the piping, and I can start to turn the housing to disconnect it, but there doesn't seem to be enough clearance to turn it very far, as shown in the picture below:
[image: pump housing removal obstructed]

The housing is in the center, with the pipe coming out the top of it.  The housing has turned just slightly counterclockwise to unscrew it from the piping, but is running against the plate attached to the filter basket to the left.  There is not enough flex to turn it much further than this.

Comment: The impellor has to be removed from the motor first.

Comment: @ojait After taking this picture I've moved the motor and attached impellor  out of the way to the right.

Answer (score 1):

The housing , after viewing the photo is attached to the discharge 1 1/2 inch plastic pipe. Although there are threads in view, you can also see a ring of glue (?) just above the pipe threads. So if there is no nut that would tighten to the pipe threads most likely you will need to cut the pipe to remove it from the housing. If the hole in the housing isn't very large you could try plugging it ,too.

Comment: So I'm guessing that whoever installed this didn't design the piping very well.  If I have to cut piping I'll want to make it so the piping doesn't have to be cut again, I assume this would be by installing a new nut somewhere,  I guess just a bit above where the pipe comes out of the housing?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what the stuff that looks like glue is, it's not the kind of glue that welds pipes together; I'm assuming I can just use teflon tape on the new fitting...

Comment: yes, it would facilitate future repairs if you didn't have to cut the pipe. The best way for this is to install a PVC union. It's hard to judge how much pipe is available , but ideally it should be positioned as close to the pump as possible. You could also put a second union just after the pre-filter.

Comment: If that ring of what I thought was glue, is something else, verify that it wasn't applied to repair a leak. It might be silicone and if so is probably sealing a leak. Now would be the best time to replace the fitting.

Comment: all the other screw-on connections (baskets and housings for other pumps) have this same glue-like stuff, so I doubt it's to seal a leak.  Also, when you say PVC union... isn't this piping ABS?

Comment: I don't believe it is (although possible). Most pressurized plumbing uses schedule 40 (sometimes 80) PVC pipe. The pipe looks dark in the photo, but I'm wondering if it wasn't painted to protect it from  UV rays which degrade it over time. Scrape the surface and see if it's white .